# React hide unknown-prop warning

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes, react-slick

I'm using a package which has an issue that causes React to console the error "unknown-prop warning", i am looking for a short-term solution to hide the error until something else can be found/used.

Is there a way to hide this?

edit: its more of a general question as to how to overall disable these errors, i want to avoid rollbar flagging it as it will cause a lot of errors in the logs.

but im using reactslick, theres numerous reported issues of this error but i never found a fix, it comes from the code snippet below: ( i believe it passes in every prop even the ones it doesnt need.

```
SliderButtonNext = () =>
<button className="react-slick-slider">
  <FaChevronRight size={24} className="arrow" />
</button>

SliderButtonPrev = () => {
    <button className="react-slick-slider">
       <FaChevronLeft size={24} className="arrow" />
    </button>
  }

const settings = {
  nextArrow: this.SliderButtonNext(),
  prevArrow: this.SliderButtonPrev(),
};
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/warnings/unknown-prop.html

Hard to tell what's going on but I figure it's
React does not yet recognize the attribute you specified.

Can you provide a sample code where you believe the warning/error is being thrown

Comment: If you're using chrome, you can right click the warning in the console and select Filter > Hide messages from...

Comment: Wich one is the unknown property?